# Java split function reading space after a character as an empty string

Tags: java, string

input: he is a good, person.

desired output: {"he","is","a","good","person"}

program output: {"he","is","a","good"," ","person"}

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        String[] ace = s.trim().split("[\\s+!,?._'@]");
        scan.close();
        System.out.println(ace.length);
        for(String c : ace)
            System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

am asking for first time here. need pointers for next time

Comment: Is your regex correct?

Comment: regex is for any space and these special characters !,?._'@

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a sequence of two delimiters between "good" and "person" - a space and a comma. You could tweak your regex to allow multiple consecutive delimiter characters as the same delimiter:

```
String[] ace = s.trim().split("[\\s+!,?._'@]+");
// Here ------------------------------------^
```

Comment: thanks. this worked .could you please tell me what that + do in the regex(i am new to programming)

Comment: @micro "+" in regex means "one or more" - so instead of the " " and the "," being treated as different delimiters, the entire sequence of ", " is treated as a single delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

You could use RegExp:

```
String[] words = str.split("\\W+");
```

This is a [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/C04YYh/1/)